# Django template javascript reload interval css

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, django-templates

I am trying to make some ajax to reload CSS class o my webpage.

I have two CSS classes for background color.

I want to change them based on the object existence, in specified interval.

The problem is that first call working ok, object do not exist so class "lewy_z" is added, but after some time when object show up the "lewy_Z" class is not removed and class "lewy_c" is not added.

Do I need something special to reload css ?

Any ideas why ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                setInterval(function () {

                    {% if place_event_now %}
                    $("#left_color").addClass("lewy_c");
                    $("#left_color").removeClass("lewy_z");
                    {% else %}
                    $("#left_color").addClass("lewy_z");
                    $("#left_color").removeClass("lewy_c");
                    {% endif %}

                }, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: Try to debug in your `setInterval` function, I think it did not call for the specific time period. would be better if you post your html markup and your python code as well. Thanks.